# Only omit NA that does not overlap with other NA in a certain column

Tags: r, dataframe, missing-data

Let say I have a data frame that looks like this :

```
>df
col1   col2   col3

 12    NA      2 
 21    11     NA
 NA     2     NA
 3     NA     NA
 NA    NA      4
 8     12      5
 41    39      9
```

I want to omit the NA, but the NA in col3 is a piece of precious information, so I don't want to fill it in with any other value without more information. Thus, I want to omit the NA that does not overlap with the NA in col3 only.

So it would look like this :

```
>df
col1   col2   col3

 21    11     NA
 NA     2     NA
 3     NA     NA
 8     12      5
 41    39      9
```

The only reason why NA in col2 and col1 is still there because deleting their row will cause the NA in col3 to be deleted also, which is what I want to prevent. Thus, I can tolerate those leftover NA from col1 and col2.

Is there any convenient way for me to do this or any package to tackle this problem? I have tried using filter :

```
df <- df %>% filter(complete.cases(df[, -3]))
```

But it became like this instead since there is overlapping NA :

```
 >df
 col1   col2   col3

 21    11     NA
 8     12      5
 41    39      9
```

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance~

Comment: How do you define the overlap?

Comment: If any of the NA on col1 or col2 is on the same row with the NA in col3, that's how I determine as overlap. Pardon my lack of vocabulary in explaining the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create a condition with `rowSums`

```
df1[!(rowSums(is.na(df1[-3])) > 0 & !is.na(df1[[3]])),]
#  col1 col2 col3
#2   21   11   NA
#3   NA    2   NA
#4    3   NA   NA
#6    8   12    5
#7   41   39    9
```

When we do the `rowSums(is.na(df1[-3])) > 0`, it is checking for any NA in the first two columns and returns TRUE for those cases

```
rowSums(is.na(df1[-3])) > 0
#[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

But, we want to remove that first row because there is no `NA` for that row in 'col3'

Next we check for `NA`s in 'col3'

```
is.na(df1[[3]])
#[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Wherever, there is TRUE, we want to keep it.  So, if we do `&`, it will return the `NA` common in both

```
(rowSums(is.na(df1[-3])) > 0 & !is.na(df1[[3]]))
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

i.e. 1st and 5th row have NA in both blocks of columns.  Negating it changes `TRUE-> FALSE` and `FALSE-> TRUE`

```
!(rowSums(is.na(df1[-3])) > 0 & !is.na(df1[[3]]))
#[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

which are the rows that can have both sets not having any NA or 'col3' having NA and other rows may or not have NA

---

Or use the same logic in `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
df1  %>%
     filter(!(rowSums(is.na(.[-3])) > 0 & !is.na(col3)))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(col1 = c(12L, 21L, NA, 3L, NA, 8L, 41L), col2 = c(NA, 
11L, 2L, NA, NA, 12L, 39L), col3 = c(2L, NA, NA, NA, 4L, 5L, 
9L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Comment: Thank you, I tried, and it works. Can you elaborate a bit so that I can understand what is going on?

Comment: @Lutfi Updated the post

Comment: Thank you so much~ That is a great explanation~!